# How to get multiple size of image without using php thumb?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have set up an admin panel for charter, yacht and other vehicles reservation and i want to upload only a single image for the vehicles and nedd to resize the images in multiple size without using phpthumb library because it takes too much time to load the listing page , first it makes the cache of the images therefore it sucks.I need a simple way for resizing single image so that admin dont have upload the multiple images of that vehicle.

Comment: One way or another, the image has to be resized. If you don't use caching, you'll have to do it on every page load. If you *do* use caching, it will only happen once - so, worst-case, after the image is uploaded, retrieve every size of image once so that the cache is populated. If you do this straight after the upload, not when the user sees the pages, the suer shouldn't get any performance hit. Of course, I assume you mean caching the resized images to disk, not simple web server caching which relies on proxies and browser config...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/image-resizing-made-easy-with-php/) is a very nice library for doing want you need.

Answer (score 0):

I use this function i made:

```
<?php
function getImageXY( $image, $type='original' ) {
    if( $type == 'original' ) {
        $imgDimsMax = 200;
    } else if( $type == 'thumb' ) {
        $imgDimsMax = 60;
    } else if( $type == 'defualt' ) {
        $imgDimsMax = 140;
    }

    $aspectRatio = 1;    // deafult aspect ratio...keep the image as is.

    // set the default dimensions.
    $imgWidth   = $imgDimsMax;
    $imgHeight  = $imgDimsMax;

    list( $width, $height, $type, $attr ) = getimagesize( $image );
    //$imgHeight    = floor ( $height * ( $imgWidth / $width ) );

    if( $width == $height ) {
        // if the image is less than ( $imgDimsMax x $imgDimsMax ), use it as is..
        if( $width < $imgDimsMax ) {
            $imgWidth   = $width;
            $imgHeight  = $height;
        }
    } else {
        if( $width > $height ) {
            // set $imgWidth to $imgDimsMax and resize $imgHeight proportionately
            $aspectRatio    = $imgWidth / $width;
            $imgHeight      = floor ( $height * $aspectRatio );
        } else if( $width < $height ) {
            // set $imgHeight to $imgDimsMax and resize $imgWidth proportionately
            $aspectRatio    = $imgHeight / $height;
            $imgWidth       = floor ( $width * $aspectRatio );
        }
    }

    return array( $imgWidth, $imgHeight );
}
?>
```

Pass it the original image and dimension type (different types give different sizes) and it returns the new width and height. Hope ie helps.